# Qual a origem do ditado "Pior a emenda que o soneto"?

Tags: significado, português-brasileiro, português-europeu, origem-histórica, ditados

Qual a origem de "Pior a emenda que o soneto"?
Do Brasil ou Portugal?

Qual a referencia mais antiga desta expressão?

Comment: Bem esta é obrigatoriamente de Portugal. Os sonetos cá estavam solidamente instalados. Não sei se "darem música" no Brasil punha a ênfase na métrica da versificação.

Comment: mas é usado tbm no Brasil, pelo menos no Sul do Brasil

Comment: Sem dúvidas ´@Peixoto, é uma expressão belíssima! Intimamente ligada à história da literatura em língua Portuguesa. Os sonetas são moda desde a idade média...É uma estrutura poética intemporal.

Comment: eu, pelo menos uso: A emenda saiu pior que o soneto",

Comment: Neste caso a emenda é uma correcção ao que está escrito em Soneto?

Comment: Ainda é bem usado no Brasil.  Mas acho que vai cair em desuso pois não ouço nenhum jovem usando a expressão.

Comment: Eu conheço da fora exata que está escrita na pergunta.  (Pior a emenda que... )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sobre a origem da expressão existe um certo folclore, como é comum em ditos populares, mas a historia mais aceita se refere ao poeta português [Manuel Maria Barbosa](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manuel_Maria_Barbosa_du_Bocage), e fala sobre a impossibilidade da correção de um soneto feito por um estudante, pois era tão ruim que um emenda apenas pioraria o soneto.

Tendo essa informação, podemos dizer que a origem é portuguesa, mas, apesar das grandes diferenças, brasileiros e portugueses ainda falam a mesma língua, então, apesar da origem,
acabou sendo incorporada ao português brasileiro também